# Is it possible to make an application’s window smaller than intended?

Tags: macos, desktop, window-manager

I’ve always had issues with some application windows in macOS where I can’t make them smaller than a certain amount.
Audio Midi Setup is the perfect example of this.

[image: Audio Midi Setup]

If you look at the image posted, you’ll see that there’s no reason why it shouldn’t be shorter, there’s a lot of vertical space which is absolutely pointless.

Airdroid, same story, lots and lots of wasted space.

I find this infuriating as I really need some windows to be smaller in order to have my desktop tidy and the apps easily accessible without having them overlap.

Does anyone know of a way to “force” an application’s window on macOS to be smaller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

You can't force an app window to get smaller than the minimum size it is programmed to be. There's no 3rd party app or macOS feature that can let you do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I’ve guessed as much by several weeks of scouring the internet. Unless I have access to the sourcecode and can modify the NSWindow minSize property, it looks like there’s no possible solution other than write to the developer and kindly ask for a modification.

Comment: @Luca Yes. Also, the developer may have a good reason to program window size this way (unless you have spotted a case which indicates otherwise). Best to get in touch with the developer, but you may not expect them to oblige every time.

Answer (score -1):

Using the "Moom" app you can quickly force apps into whatever tile size and grid position you want using keyboard shortcuts. Super-helpful when using large screens and/or many screens. My biggest productivity booster app! But yes, even "Moom" can't force app windows to be smaller than their minimum size.

Answer (score -1):

kinda late on this but maybe u still search for something. It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but I found this app that can turn every window or display into a (optionally native) picture-in-picture window through live streaming it's content. Only downside is, that you can't interact with the content.
Here it is: https://github.com/amitv87/PiP/